# Convert word document "*.doc" a4 in to letter

Tags: vba, batch

What is the function in VBA to convert and save an A4 formatted documento into letter size?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `PageSetup.PaperSize` property.

To set the paper size to A4

`Documents(1).PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA4`

To set the paper size to Legal

`Documents(1).PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperLegal`

To save any changes, use

`If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then ActiveDocument.Save`